After upgrading ubuntu22.04 to ubuntu24.04, Error, pkgProblemResolver
After upgrading ubuntu22.04 to ubuntu24.04, after command with "sudo apt --fix-broken install": E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. E: Unable to correct dependencies
This is different from previous, because it is new issue when update ubuntu22.04 to ubuntu24.o4.

Step1: sudo apt --fix-broken install
Step2: sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <"package name">
to remove the packages listed by step1
If python3.12-minimal or python3 that can not be deleted: download deb file from:https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/python3.12-minimal
install it with: sudo dpkg -i python3.12-minimal_3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt --fix-broken install will run without errors.

Warning: --force-remove-reinstreq is called the "nuclear option". It will eliminate the package, but will also leave fallout across your filesystem that must be manually cleaned up. The presence of remaining files may prevent re-installation of packages. If you need to use it, then something has gone very wrong with your system.
